# How to get the content of an iframe in angular5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I am trying to program a WYSIWYG for an app. Everything seems to be okay , except that I can't get the value of the iframe, without the `[object HTMLBodyElement]`

```
let content = this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body
```

When I `console.log(content)`, I get `<body>...</body>` but trying to store it to database, it says its an `[object HTMLBodyElement]`.

I have tried converting the iframe value to a string but not luck.

How can I get the value of the iframe as a string?

Is the any better way of doing this, for instance moving the value of the Iframe to a textarea then get the textarea value in component class?

Comment: `this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body.outerHTML` or `this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body.innerHTML` maybe solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let content = this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body
```

is giving to you the element not the string html for this you need to use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

`this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body.outerHT‌​ML`

or [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp):

`this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body.innerHT‌​ML`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using inner HTML

```
this.richtextarea.nativeElement.contentDocument.body.innerHT‌ML
```

Hope this helps you